# Spring Controllers and Services

Tags: design, spring, services

we are at the middle of a project. It's a REST Service. Now we have controllers to handle the Requestmappings and the forwarding to the Services. 
A concrete example we have a UserController, GroupController, UserService and a GroupService.

The user controller has as injection the UserService and the GroupController has as injection the GroupService. (one to one dependency)

When I create/update/delete a user then the scenario is simple: userControllers tells the userService and it do this.

Now the system has a lot of other controller/services that are going to be added.
But what I don't know is: what is the best way when I have to to mix user/group action?
For example: I have to add a user in a group. But I must check that the user exists, that the group exists and after save the information in the user (Entity/DTO) that the user is now port of this group.

1) schould I manage all from the userController:
-userService.checkUser()
-groupService.checkGroup()
-userService.updateUser()

2) or schould I manage al from the userService:
-userService.addUser()
(in the userService then:
  -checkUser()
  -checkGroup()
  -updateUser()
)

In the solution 1 what I don't like is the injection of some other Services that not belongs to users
In the solution 2 I have the idea that I'm going to replicate concepts that exists on the groupServices...

The exapmle above is only a litle part of the great picture. But that what i would understand is how can I design this part to don't have a lot dependency and a lot of code replication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want to structure your layers (controller, service, persistence).

Ideally controllers shouldn't mess with all the business logic, that's what services are for. The exception is for surface checks (validation, nullity, types).

Try to keep the [**Single responsibility principle**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) in mind to help you structure correctly your code.

That's why I recommend what you describe as the solution 2.

Comment: Ok. You're suggestion ist to go in direction of solution 2.

Comment: Solution 2, it is ! @java4fun